# How can I calculate the equilibrium between several reactions?

Tags: equilibrium

If I mix xNaOH + yCdCl2 + zZnCl2 in an aqueous medium, how can I calculate the final equilibrium quantities of the resulting salts (which I suppose may be the following):

Q1 NaOH
Q2 CdCl2
Q3 ZnCl2
Q4 NaCl
Q5 Cd(OH)2
Q6 Zn(OH)2

Also (only if it will take more than an hour for >99.999% of the reaction to occur), how can I calculate the respective quantities of each vs time?

Suppose the reaction occurs at ~25C, unless a better prescribed temperature is suggested.

Comment: Don't think in terms of salts (which, BTW, half of these aren't), think in terms of individual ions and their concentrations. Write down all conservation laws, solubility equations, etc. See where this gets you.

Comment: Is this in the solid state or in aqueous solution? Also, the x, y, z are meant as initial amounts or concentrations, not as stoichiometric coefficients, right?

Comment: @KarstenTheis This is in aqueous solution (I didn't think of specifying but now corrected thanks to your comment). Your assumption is correct, x, y and z are the initial amounts (I probably could have written it more clearly as Q1(t=0), and Q1(t= n), Q1 (final) or something the like).